# What does variable = [self] mean?

Tags: python, oop

We just received this piece of code, and I don't understand what `_todo = [ self ]` means.

```
class ABR(object):
    def __init__(self,ordre,root=None):
        self.__root = None
        assert ordre in (lt,gt,leq,geq)
        self.__order = ordre
        if isinstance(root,Sommet):
            self.__root = root

    def __str__(self):
        """ effectue un parcours infixe """
        _todo = [ self ]
        _done = "[ "
        while _todo != [] :
            _next = _todo.pop(0)
            if _next != None :
                if isinstance(_next,Sommet):
                    _done += "%s, " % _next.val
                elif not _next.estVide:
                    if _next.hasRightSubTree :
                        _todo.insert(0,_next.rightSubTree)
                    _todo.insert(0,_next.racine)
                    if _next.hasLeftSubTree :
                        _todo.insert(0,_next.leftSubTree)
        return _done[:-2]+" ]"
```

Comment: `self` refers to an instance of the `ABR` class.

Comment: `_todo = [ self ]` is a local variable list object that have `class instance` in it.

Comment: `_todo` is a local variable that is initialized with the current instance (object) of `ABR` class as the first element of the list. It looks like an inorder traversal of an abstract binary tree to me, returning the last 2 elements of the binary tree.

Comment: A couple of asides:  First, if your tree is empty this method will return `" ]"` instead of `"[ ]"`.  Second, building a string with `+=` is very inefficient in Python because a new string is created with each append.  If your tree is large this will become very costly.  Instead, investigate using `str.join` for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `_todo = [ self ]` creates a list named `_todo` with a single element which is the object on which the `__str__` method is called. (The `__str__` method is typically called by the `print` statement.)

That variable is then subsequently used to prepend/append the string representation of the children to create a flatten representation of the tree.